# How to run the specific branch of bitbucket in Jenkins pipeline repository through triggers

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, webhooks, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

To setup Bitbucket and Jenkins Pipeline , I am using  [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/generic-webhook-trigger-plugin) in Jenkins.

- I Enable it in the pipeline job.
- Configure hte token string
- Add the plugin endpoint in Bitbucket.
  JENKINS_URL/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=whatever_you_picked

this is my pipeline code for cloning the repo

```
pipeline{
    parameters {
        gitParameter branchFilter: 'origin/(.*)', defaultValue: 'dev', name: 'BRANCH_NAME', type: 'PT_BRANCH'
   
    }
stage("clone"){
        checkout([  
        $class: 'GitSCM', 
        branches: [[name: "{parms.BRANCH_NAME}"]], 
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
        extensions: [], 
        submoduleCfg: [], 
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "${GIT_CREDENTIAL_ID}", url: "${REPO_URL}"]]
       ])
}
```

It is always cloning the dev repo , whenever any branch code is pushed to bitbucket , but I want to clone that repository that is just pushed recently . There is probably a way from JSONfile , but i am not getting how to do that

Comment: On your bitbucket hook configuration page you can see the payload (JSON) that bitbucket is sending to Jenkins, in the Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin configuration you can extract parameters from the payload and use them in the build - one of the parameters is the source branch.

Answer (score 0):

We're building our branches using a "MultiBranch Pipeline" project which includes a jenkinsfile in each branch.  The MultiBranch Pipeline acts as both a folder and a triggerable job.  The jenkinsfile in Bitbucket gets merged like all other code.

[Hello World Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/)

Have your Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin trigger the MultiBranch Pipeline job.  This will then scan all branches in your repository and trigger a build for any which have changes since it was last scanned.

In the Jenkinsfile, you can use env.BRANCH_NAME set by Jenins at build time to pull the branch code you're building at the moment.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Prebuild') {
            steps{
                script{
                    if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master'){                
                        git credentialsId: 'myCreds', url: 'myGitUrl'
                    }
                    else{
                        git branch: env.BRANCH_NAME, credentialsId: 'myCreds', url: 'myGitUrl'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but we are not putting our jenkinsfile in the source code repository . so is there any other way also to do the same